# Get the JSON objects that are not present in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, lodash

I have two arrays.

```
array1 = [
 {'id':1},
 {'id': 2}
]
```

and

```
array2 = [
 {'idVal':1},
 {'idVal': 2},
 {'idVal': 3},
 {'idVal': 4}
]
```

I need a optimal way, lodash if possible so that i can compare these two arrays and get a result array that has object present in `array2` and not in `array1`. The keys have different name in both arrays. So the result will be,

```
res = [
  {'idVal': 3},
  {'idVal': 4}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#differenceWith) with a comparator method. According to the docs about `_.difference()` (differenceWith is based on difference):

> Creates an array of array values not included in the other given
>   arrays using SameValueZero for equality comparisons. The order and
>   references of result values are determined by the first array.

So `array2` should be the 1st param passed to the method.

```js
var array1 = [
  {'id': 1},
  {'id': 2}
];

var array2 = [
  {'idVal': 1},
  {'idVal': 2},
  {'idVal': 3},
  {'idVal': 4}
];

var result = _.differenceWith(array2, array1, function(arrVal, othVal) {
  return arrVal.idVal === othVal.id;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ES6

```
const result = array2.filter(item => !array1.find(i => i.idVal === item.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [
 {'id':1},
 {'id': 2},
 {'id': 3},
 {'id': 4}
]

var array2 = [
 {'id':1},
 {'id': 3},
 {'id': 4}
]

notInArray2 = array1.reduce( function(acc, v) {
  if(!array2.find(function (vInner) {
    return v.id === vInner.id;
  })){
    acc.push(v);
  }
  return acc
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(notInArray2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an optimized solution, not using lodash though. I created a search index containing just the values of `array1`, so that you can look up elements in O(1), rather than going through the entire `array1` for every element in `array2`.

Let `m` be the size of `array1` and `n` be the size of `array2`. This solution will run in `O(m+n)`, as opposed  to `O(m*n)` that you would have without prior indexing.

```js
const array1 = [
 {'id':1},
 {'id': 2}
];

const array2 = [
 {'idVal':1},
 {'idVal': 2},
 {'idVal': 3},
 {'idVal': 4}
];

const array1ValuesIndex = {};
array1.forEach(entry => array1ValuesIndex[entry.id] = true);

const result = array2.filter(entry => !array1ValuesIndex[entry.idVal]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1 = [
 {'id':1},
 {'id': 2}
]

array2 = [
 {'idVal':1},
 {'idVal': 2},
 {'idVal': 3},
 {'idVal': 4}
]

var array1Keys=array1.map(function(d1){ return d1.id});

var result =array2.filter(function(d){ return array1Keys.indexOf(d.idVal)==-1 })
console.log(result);
```